# Inserting an image inside a table cell in Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs-api

Is it possible to insert an image directly inside a cell in Google Docs using the API? I wanted to put an image only on the first column in a 1x2 table cell. I've read the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/docs_v1.documents.html#batchUpdate), `**insertInlineImage**` said: `The image must be inserted inside the bounds of an existing Paragraph. For instance, it cannot be inserted at a table's start index (i.e. between the table and its preceding paragraph). Inline images cannot be inserted inside a footnote or equation.`

How do I do this in Google Docs python?

[Image in a Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSEa4.png)

Comment: In your situation, is this information useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/gdoctableapppy

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this, I'll check this out. I also found GDoc's API too difficult to digest.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. Also, I thought that the document for creating a table using Docs API might be a bit complicated. So, I created a library for easily creating a table using Docs API. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you can either:

1. Use a library like https://github.com/tanaikech/gdoctableapppy to make things slightly easier
2. Write the process yourself, the process is as follows:

   1. Insert a placeholder tag where you want your image to be inside a table,  e.g. `{{myImage}}`
   2. Do a batch update on the document, where you:

      1. Search for this placeholder tag, and delete it
      2. Insert an inline image at the location where this tag was

One current limitation is that image must be accessible from a public URL (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/images)), there is currently a [feature request/bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148814758?pli=1) to allow images to be uploaded too